# How do I find the smallest distinct groups out of a set of groups of integers?

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have a class as follows...

```
public class IntGroup {
  public string GroupName {get; set;}
  public List<int> Integers {get; set;}
}
```

...and I have several instances, each containing a collection of integers. I want to find the smallest sets of groups that contain distinct integers.

For example, if I have the following groups...

Group 1 contains 1, 2, 3
Group 2 contains 4, 5, 6
Group 3 contains 4, 5, 9

...then as group 1 contains three integers that aren't in any other group, it on its own is a smallest set of groups (in this case, a set of one). Groups 2 and 3 together are another smallest set, in that you need both groups to be together (as they both contain 4 and 5), but they don't need group 1.

I would like to write some C# code that would help me find these smallest groups. It's the sort of problem that I feel could be very elegantly solved in Linq, but I can't work out how.

Anyone able to help? By the way, this isn't a homework question, I'm a 51 year-old programmer, looking to solve part of a much bigger problem to do with building trees of function calls, and wanting to find distinct parts of the tree.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define this class first:

```
class ValueIEnumerableComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        return obj.Sum(i => i.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Then, you can use this chain:

```
int[][] groups =
{
    new[] {1, 2, 3}, 
    new[] {4, 5, 6},
    new[] {4, 5, 9}
};
var result = groups.
    GroupBy(array => groups.
        Where(other => array != other).
        SelectMany(other => array.Intersect(other)), 
            new ValueIEnumerableComparer<int>()).
    Select(g => g.ToArray()).
    ToArray();
```

What it does is group the arrays by their intersections, then select only the array from the group. Defining a class implementing `IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>` was necessary. I couldn't find a better way to extract a key on two sequences without defining a comparer which would compare their elements. Its `GetHashCode()` method isn't really fancy but works for this example.

It can also be easily adapted to your case, but I thought that bringing a general one would be more helpful for whoever reads the question.

Comment: Hello Eve, thanks for the reply. I'm having some trouble compiling your code, as it's giving an error on the SelectMany(array.Intersect) bit. Both SelectMany and Intersect are underlined in red, although I suspect that fixing the Intesect one may fix the other. The error on Intersect is "Cannot choose method from method group. Did you intend to invoke the method?" The error on the SelectMany is "The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage" Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Hello, are you using my sample or have you already adapted it to your code? If it's the latter, could you please write the version which you are using? My sample compiles fine for me, I'm using .NET 4.5. Works fine with 3.5 as well.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Try to replace the parameter passed to `SelectMany` (the method group) with: `other => array.Intersect(other)`.

Comment: Hello again. I just figured out that I needed to add the => into Intersect before seeing your reply! That compiles now, but when I run it, I just get the three lists back. I'm using .NET4, and I'm using your code verbatim at the moment. I'm just enumerating over the result, the arrays in it, and the ints in them. Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: Aaarrrggghhh! Stupid me can't even read what's on the screen! It did the job perfectly, I just misread the output! This answer is brilliant. Please adjust the code in your sample by adding the => and I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks very much :)

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel It's very strange, adding the lambda operator (`=>`) isn't necessary for the program to run fine -- As writing `array.Intersect` (but be careful, *without the parentheses*) is equivalent to passing a method group. I wonder if maybe there's some conflict in your code with another extension method called `Intersect` but with a different signature, somewhere. I can guarantee you, though, that the above code ran in a pure context will not fail to compile. I'll still adapt it, to match your case.

Comment: Hi Eve. The Intersect I have is the one in System.Linq, and I haven't added any other. I was testing this in a small sample project, without any extra code. Anyway, it's working, so I'm not worried :) However, I do have a more serious problem, and that is when I run this in my real code, if there are a lot of groups, I run into an overflow exception in the ValueIEnumerableComparer's GetHashCode method. Any idea how I get round this? Thanks again.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Try to replace the method's body with: `var hash = 0; foreach (var item in obj) hash += item.GetHashCode(); return hash;`.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel The above happened because `Sum()` happens in a `checked` context, and since we were summing hash codes it was likely that it'd happen.

Comment: Me again! I have tried to adapt this code to a slightly more complex scenario, and failed. As I can't type much in these comments, I have put the zipped sample project here http://dotnetwhatnot.pixata.co.uk/mybits/FindingSmallestSetsOfGroups.zip - Would you be able to have a quick look and see how I can modify the Linq to account for this case? If you look in the ReadMe.txt file in the project, there is a (rather wordy due to the time of night) explanation of what I'm trying to do. Thanks very much.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I'll take a look later and write here again.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I hadn't had much time to check it out yet but a possible solution could be editing the first `Where` clause so that it considers only methods which call other ones, in this way: `.Where(m => m.Public && m.CallsAll.Count > 0)`. Please drop a comment saying if that nails the problem or works around it, I'll read it later when I'm home.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not the problem. It happens that in the sample code, the FerretFun public method doesn't call anything else, but that's a red herring. The problem is that the Linq you kindly posted only looks in the CallsAll collection to build the groups, it doesn't look at the parent method itself. It's very hard to discuss in these teeny little comments. I don't know if there's a better way to do it, but if you don't mind to email me directly (mryossu@hotmail.com), I can explain in more detail, if if/when we find a solution, we can post it back here to help others. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get chance to look at this? Thanks

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I've sent you a mail. Let me know how it works for you.